# why cant i access class A function in following code?

Tags: c++, inheritance

the error i get for `obj.a::get();` is class a is inaccessible, i know that `obj.get()`would flag an error, but i guess this should work, whats the issue here?

```
class a {
    int arg1;
public:
    a(int i){
        arg1 = i;
        cout << "a() called" << endl;
    }

    void get() {
        cout << "arg1=" << arg1 << endl;
    }
};


class b {
    int arg2;
public:
    b(int j) {
        arg2 = j;
        cout << "b() called" << endl;
    }

    void get() {
        cout << "arg2=" << arg2 << endl;
    }
};

class c: private a, private b {
    int arg3;
public:
    c(int i, int j, int k): b(k), a(j) {
        arg3 = k;
        cout << "c() called" << endl;
    }
};

int main() {
    c obj(1, 2, 3);
    obj.a::get();
}
```

Comment: You are inheriting from `a` as private. So `a` is not directly accessible from `c`

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`c` uses `private` to derive from `a`, so the `a` subobject of `c` is inaccessible from functions which are not member functions of `c`.

Comment: This `c obj(1,2,3); obj.a::get();` makes me think, that's not the only problem.

Comment: @KirilKirov: Perhaps I am missing something obvious, but... why so?

Comment: `class a` is base class (even thought `private`) of `class c`. Having the code in the question, even if `a` was a `public` derived, can you access base class' function like this: `obj.a::get(); /*where obj is object c*/`? Or I'm missing something here?

Comment: `get()` is defined in both `classes a and b` so when he inherits them in `c` there would be ambiguity. `::` should resolve it

Comment: @KirilKirov: I would say you can. See, for instance, [this](http://ideone.com/U77jDM).

Comment: Wow, I wasn't familiarized with this kind of syntax o.O You're right, my bad. // +1